# How to decrypt pgp file using rsa key

Tags: javascript, security, encryption

I have been given a file which is encrypted in a pgp format. It's been encrypted using my public RSA key.

I am trying to decrypt the file using my RSA private key in a dummy node application.

```
const NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');
const key = new NodeRSA('*INSERT KEY HERE*');

const encryptedMsg = '*INSERT ENCRYPTED KEY HERE*';

const decrypted = key.decrypt(encryptedMsg, 'utf8');
console.log(decrypted);
```

but getting the following: `Error("Key format must be specified")`.

Is it possible to decrypt a pgp file using a rsa key?

Comment: Have you entered the key with newline-characters? According to the [node-rsa documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters), the newline-characters must be included in the `INSERT KEY HERE`-String.

Comment: @Mime yes the newline-characters are included

Comment: Another problem could be that you protected your private key with a passwort, which `node-rsa` does not support according to [this issue](https://github.com/rzcoder/node-rsa/issues/98). Also see [this issue](https://github.com/rzcoder/node-rsa/issues/188)